# XMLHttpRequest not sent if web page location is changed afterwards

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

At some point my webpage is changing its `location.href`, resulting in the browser navigating to another page.

**I would like to do a XHR POST request just before changing the page.**
I would rather not wait for this XHR request completion, because not receiving 100% of the requests is OK but speed is paramount.

I tried this code, however **the XHR request is NOT send by Firefox/Chrome, because of the `location.href` change right after**.

```
<html>
<head></<head>
<body>

This is page test1.htm<br>
<input type="button" value="Go!" onclick="go();">

<script>
function go() {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { /* Do nothing */ };
    xhr.open('POST', '/cgi-bin/hb.exe?action=remoteapppost', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send('action=remoteapppost&id=TEST');

        // ==> this XHR request is NOT sent because of the following line:

    location.href = "test2.htm";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I do a breakpoint or move the `location.href = "...";` inside the callback, everything is working fine (of course).

Any idea on how to send a XHR request just before leaving a webpage?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a combination of the `beforeunload` event and the new `navigator.sendBeacon()` API that's designed to not block navigation.